# Can the ranger choose powers from the scout or hunter list?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, ranger

I would like to create a ranger with some Scout or Hunter powers, but I don't know if it's possible.

Furthermore, when reading the Scout description, at first level I find a column with the class features and the powers, but I can't distinguish them from each other.

Which are the Scout's class features and which are the Scout's powers?

Comment: Hi Carl, welcome to the site!  This is a good first question. Please take a look around the site and look at the [FAQ].

Comment: Also note that feats exist to fiddle some of the encounter powers.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes,** it's possible to select Scout or Hunter powers **if they have a specified level.**

As a general rule, when a member of a class is eligible to select:

- an At-Will Attack,
- an Encounter Attack,
- a Daily Attack
- or any Utility power,

**and a level is specified**, he can select a power **of the same type and of lower or equal level** from any homonymous class.

So, for example, a *Player's Handbook 1* Ranger may select [Speed of the Zephyr](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13632)<sup>DDI</sup> (described as Ranger Utility 22) upon reaching 22<sup>nd</sup> level.

A 1<sup>st</sup> Mage Wizard from *Heroes of the Fallen Lands* may select [Thunderwave](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1169) (a Wizard At-Will Attack 1) from *Player's Handbook 1* and vice versa.

A *Player's Handbook 1* Paladin cannot select [Righteous Radiance](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13554) as one of its powers at 1<sup>st</sup> level (because that power is described as a Paladin Attack). He can however, select the [Strike of Hope](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13575) power (because it is described as a Paladin Attack 1, that is: it has a level).

---

**Those listed in the class shaded box are all class features.**

Some class features are expressed as powers (in fact, they *provide* powers). Other powers are taken with the character normal advancement.  I think you are interested into telling the difference between these two.
Most *Player's Handbook 1*, *2* and *3* classes share the same advancement in power selection (called AEDU). **AEDU** stands for At-will/Encounter/Daily/Utilities. All have they unique class features gained at 1<sup>st</sup> level, but then, they all gain powers at the same pace (as you could find out on a big table in *PH1*).
*Heroes of Fallen Lands* and *Heroes of Forgotten Kingdoms* classes (as well as other subsequent classes) exited the AEDU paradigm by providing another approach. Class features are granted throughout the whole career, and occasionally you select powers from a list, so the difference between a *class feature* and a *vanilla power* has thinned.

However, if the distinction is important for you, you have some clues when deciding if something listed in the class breakout is a class feature or a vanilla power.

1. If the element is a power that has a level and a class, it is not a class feature.
2. If the element is found under the **Class features** list in the class shaded box, it is a class feature.
3. If the element listed in the class breakout has a name that ends with "power" probably it is not a class feature.

**Examples:**

1. Hunters and Scouts receive [Reactive Shift](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13600) at 5<sup>th</sup> level. The power has the label "Ranger Utility 5" in the upper right corner of its block. Having a level, it **is not** *a class feature*.
2. Hunter class has the [Disruptive Shot](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13588) entry listed under its shaded box. The provided power **is** *a class feature*.
3. A 10<sup>th</sup>-level Scout may select an Utility power (the subclass lists [Eyes of the Owl](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13610), [Root Gate](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13627), and [Verdant Flames](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13612), but he is not limited to these ones). The class breakdown names this entry as "Level 10 Scout Utility **Power**". The selected power **is not** *a class feature*.

This is also a clue to when a power derives from a class feature: if it hasn't a level, chances are that it is provided by a class feature or feat.

Comment: @waxeagle Utility ones do have. See, for example _Bridge of Roots_ (an Utility 2 listed under the Hunter subclass), _Reactive Shift_ (Utility 5, listed under both the Hunter and Scout subclasses), _Oak Skin_ (Utility 2 listed under the Scout subclass), _Veil of Winter_ (Utility 22), or _Speed of the Zephyr_ (Utility 22). Note that even if they are listed under different subclasses (the subclasses that probably are most interested in taking them), these powers are all tied to the Ranger and may be selected by any Ranger.

Comment: I want thank you gentlemen for having enlightened these rules, it is very kind of you to help me and grant me a little of your time.

Comment: @ErikBurigo great edit.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the powers for scout and hunter are described.

In the case of both the scout and the hunter, all of the At-Will powers are described as `Ranger Utilities` and are not eligible to be take as L1 At-Will attack powers for a regular Ranger (you may be able to grab them by taking a feat, I'm not sure right off hand). The `Ranger Attack` encounter powers they have cannot be chosen by a Ranger because they do not have a level associated with them.

The Scout/Ranger's At-will and Encounter Utilities are technically powers, but they result from class features. This is a function of the fact that they are essentials characters rather than PHB1-3 characters and are not built the same way. They do not have At-Will attacks outside of their melee and ranged basic attacks*.

*The caveat here is if they are human they get to choose an At-Will from the Ranger's list, or take Heroic Effort.